# Number of ways John and Mary can each select $4$ ice-cream flavours at two stores that sell one common flavour

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

John and Mary are going to host an ice-cream party. They want to provide $8$ different flavours. John goes to store A to buy the first $4$ ice cream and Mary goes to store B to buy the other $4$ ice-cream. Assume that there are $7$ different flavours sold in each store; and store A and store B share $1$ similar flavour (ex:store A and Store B both have the Vanilla flavour). Calculate the number of possible ice- cream combinations when they buy the ice cream! (Different orders are not considered as different combinations)

The problem is I can't find the repetitive part. I think it is just $C(7,4) \cdot C(7,4)=1225$. Even I count it in different cases, it still adds up to be $1225$.

Comment: Can you count the combinations for each of the three cases: 1. Only John buys Vanilla; 2. Only Mary buys Vanilla; 3. Both do not buy Vanilla?

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I can't find the repetitive part. I think it is just C(7,4)*C(7,4)=1225. Even I count it in different cases, it still adds up to be 1225.

Comment: In future, you should show your attempt and explain where you are stuck in the question itself rather than in the comments, where they might be missed.  There is an expectation at this site that when you pose a question that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Showing what you have attempted and explaining where you are stuck helps users of this site write answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: +1 Why the Downvote?

Comment: @KhushrajRathod  I moved the attempt from the comments to the question itself.  I imagine that initially there was no attempt, thereby prompting the down votes and close votes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The invalid cases, instead of repetition, of $\binom74\binom74$ are when both people buy the common flavour (i.e. vanilla).

The number of cases that this happens is $\binom63\binom 63$. So the answer is

$$\binom74\binom74-\binom63\binom63 = 1225-20^2 = 825$$

---

The additive and subtractive answers here show the identity:

$$\begin{align*}
\binom nr^2 &= \left[\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}r\right]^2\\
&= \binom{n-1}{r-1}^2 + 2\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n-1}r  + \binom{n-1}r^2
\end{align*}$$

In particular, $n=7$ and $r = 4$.

Comment: That's a nice usage of Pascal's identity you got there Peter ;) beautiful, thanks for sharing. I like how you used that: $ \binom n r^2 - \binom{n-1}{r-1}^2=\binom{n-1}{r}^2 + 2\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n-1}r $.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with $\binom{7}{4} \cdot \binom{7}{4}$ is that you include all cases where they both end up buying the same ice cream. We want to avoid those cases, or John and Mary just need to communicate a bit better ;)

The comment provided  by Peterwhy gave a good case distinction:

**Case 1:** John definitely buys the common flavour, so Mary shouldn't:
$ 1 \cdot\binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{4}$

Here the $1$ represents vanilla, then there are 6 flavours left from which John can pick $3$ each. Mary has to still pick $4$ flavours, but not vanilla.

**Case 2:** John does not buy the common flavour, so Mary should:
$1 \cdot \binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{4}$  (symmetric)

We don't really care about John or Mary, they're different people, but as long as we get our ice cream!

**Case 3:** Neither picks the common flavour:
$\binom{6}{4} \cdot \binom{6}{4}$

oh well, we can live without vanilla I guess.
If we add this all up we get $2 \cdot \binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{4} + \binom64 ^2= \binom64(2 \binom63 + \binom64)=15 \cdot (2\cdot 20+15)=15 \cdot(55)=825.$

Comment: Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You could accept an answer thought.